# How to enhance a general module entity with application specific properties?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

i am currently working on a library that handles the spring security setup to integrate several applications with a general sign in application. Of course i defined a User Entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Data
@ToString(of = { "username", "uuid" }, callSuper = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "username", callSuper = false)
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User implements UserDetails {

@Id
@NotNull
private String username;

private String uuid;

private String displayName;

private String email;

... //the usual stuff
}
```

Each application has it's own requirements and needs to enhance the user with more properties. How could this be done?

I thought about using aspectj (i use lombok, so that would be not my first choice), there must be another way?

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: Whats wrong with extending the `User` class for every application?

Comment: How about JPA inheritance? Each application would derive from User which could act as @MappedSuperclass

Comment: The problem is that i have several services and spring data repositories in that library, they all use the User entity. I think i have to use a managed entity for that and can't use a mapped superclass. That means i can't really extend the User class (if i am wrong on this one, please tell me why).